# Spring cloud stream and consume multiple kafka topics

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-integration

I have an issue with spring-boot-stream during some attempts for consume multiple topics in one `@StreamListener`.

According to spring-cloud-stream docs:
Accordidng to docs:

> **destination**
>
> The target destination of a channel on the bound
>   middleware (e.g., the RabbitMQ exchange or Kafka topic). If the
>   channel is bound as a consumer, it **could be bound to multiple
>   destinations and the destination names can be specified as comma
>   separated String values**. If not set, the channel name is used instead.
>   The default value of this > property cannot be overridden.

But, after i had been using next config:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        testchannel:
          group: test
          destination: platform.metrics, platform.sleuth
```

And now i had next error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Topic name can only have ASCII alphanumerics, '.', '_' and '-'
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.utils.KafkaTopicUtils.validateTopicName(KafkaTopicUtils.java:39) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:107) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:60) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:110) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

How to bind multiple topics to one `@StreamListner` or generate dynamic streamListeners from topic list?

Comment: [Related gitter discussion](https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream?at=59465604f6a78eab485d7b25).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to replace the space between the comma and the next destination value and it will look like:

```
spring:
    cloud:
        stream:
            bindings:
                testchannel:
                    group: test
                    destination: platform.metrics,platform.sleuth
```

Comment: Doesn't spring cloud stream kafka binder support topicPattern?

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote more details on how to send messages to dynamic destinations and how to receive messages from dynamic destinations.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56446574/4587961

As Varun Miglani said, topics are separated with comma without whitespaces.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        consumer:
          concurrency: 2
          partitioned: true
      bindings:
        # inputs
        input:
          group: application_name_group
          destination: topic-1,topic-2
          content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

To send a message dynamically, use **BinderAwareChannelResolver** and **dynamicDestinations** property.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      dynamicDestinations: output.topic.1,output.topic2,output.topic.3
```