# Spring Cloud Streams - Multiple dynamic destinations for sources and sinks

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

There was a change request on my system, which currently listens to multiple channels and send messages to multiple channels as well, but now the destination names will be in the database and change any time.
I'm having trouble believing I'm the first one to come across this, but I see limited information out there.

All I found is these 2...
Dynamic sink destination:
https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/router/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-router, but how would that work to active listening to those channels the way it's done by @StreamListener?

Dynamic source destinations:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/source-samples/dynamic-destination-source/, which does this

```
@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sourceChannel")
    public ExpressionEvaluatingRouter router() {
        ExpressionEvaluatingRouter router = new ExpressionEvaluatingRouter(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("payload.id"));
        router.setDefaultOutputChannelName("default-output");
        router.setChannelResolver(resolver);
        return router;
    }
```

But what's that "payload.id"? And where are the destinations specified there??

Comment: If this is a custom app, you can use the strategies used in this sample as a blueprint for a solution. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/source-samples/dynamic-destination-source

Comment: I saw that example, but I failed to see how the destination is being passed here @Bean
 @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sourceChannel")
 public ExpressionEvaluatingRouter router() {
  ExpressionEvaluatingRouter router = new ExpressionEvaluatingRouter(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("payload.id"));
  router.setDefaultOutputChannelName("default-output");
  router.setChannelResolver(resolver);
  return router;
 }

Comment: Don't put code in comments. It is hard to read. Edit the question instead and comment on the answer that you have done so.

Comment: Do you have experience with something like this?? Or know someone who does?

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to improve my answer, I hope it will help others.

Now the code (It worked in my debugger). This is an example, not production ready!

### This is how to send a message to dynamic destination

```
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BinderAwareChannelResolver;


@Service
@EnableBinding
public class MessageSenderService {

    @Autowired
    private BinderAwareChannelResolver resolver;

    @Transactional
    public void sendMessage(final String topicName, final String payload) {
        final MessageChannel messageChannel = resolver.resolveDestination(topicName);
        messageChannel.send(new GenericMessage<String>(payload));
    }
}
```

And configuration for Spring Cloud Stream.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      dynamicDestinations: output.topic.1,output.topic2,output.topic.3
```

I found here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#dynamicdestination
It will work in spring Cloud Stream version 2+. I use 2.1.2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

---

### This is how to consume a message from dynamic destination

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56148190/4587961

Configuration

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        consumer:
          concurrency: 2
          partitioned: true
      bindings:
        # inputs
        input:
          group: application_name_group
          destination: topic-1,topic-2
          content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

Java consumer.

```
@Component
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class CommonConsumer {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommonConsumer.class);

    @StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT)
    public void consumeMessage(final Message<Object> message) {
        logger.info("Received a message: \nmessage:\n{}", message.getPayload());

        final String topic = message.getHeaders().get("kafka_receivedTopic");

        // Here I define logic which handles messages depending on message headers and topic.
        // In my case I have configuration which forwards these messages to webhooks, so I need to have mapping topic name -> webhook URI.
    }
}
```

Comment: but how is it consuming messages from dynamic destinations, if the destinations are already specified in property input.destinations?

Comment: I meant by **dynamic** that you do not create interfaces with `@EnableBinding`. In case you want to go further, please research, how to initialize message channel spring beans. Keep in mind, kafka may not allow to create topics dynamically (it depends on kafka configuration)